# go back to password page after closing the app or after an interval of time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to IOS development, I have a password login application, 
when I close the application (click the home button), 
or the phone locks, or even after an interval of time, 
I need the app to take me to the password page again, 
what is the best way to do this? 
I have found stuff like:

```
if (UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification){
    ...do something
}

 if (applicationWillResignActive){
    ...do something
}
```

but what is the best way to use them?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add your login screen code in Life cycle of application did become active in App delegate.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
```

Use this

```
[self performSelector:@selector(LoginScreenFunction)
           withObject:nil
           afterDelay:5.0f];
```

This for open login screen after 5 second,set your time for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can pop your view controller when your application gone in background like below.

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
for( int i=0;i<[viewControllers count];i++){
    id obj=[viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
    if([obj isKindOfClass:[LoginViewController class]]){
        [[self navigationController] popToViewController:obj animated:NO];
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Publish an NSNotification in all the places where you want to show the password login page.

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"PresentLoginPasswordView" 
        object:self];
```

For example places like,

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
- inactive timer function

After that, you should subscribe to the published notification (probably inside the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method) and in the handler, you can present the login password view controller.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(presentLoginView:) 
        name:@"PresentLoginPasswordView"
        object:nil];
```